# Java v Scala from a concurrency viewpoint

Tags: java, scala, comparison, functional-programming, imperative

I am kicking off my final year project right now.  I am going to be investigating the concurrency approaches from java and scala perspectives.  Having come out of a java concurrency module, I can see why people say that the shared state threading approach is difficult to reason about.  You have critical sections to worry about, run the risk of race conditions and deadlocks etc due to the non deterministic way in which java threads operate.  With 1.5 this reasoning was given some clarity ,but still, far from crystal clear.

At first view, scala appears to remove this complex reasoning through the actors class.  This has given the programmer the ability to develop concurrent systems from a more sequential viewpoint and easier to conceptualize.  But, for this positive, am I right in saying that there are some drawbacks?  For instance, say we want to sort a large list in both scenarios - with java you create two threads split the list in two, worry about the critical sections, atomic actions etc and go code.  With scala, because it is "share nothing" you actually have to pass the list/2 to two actors to peform the sort operation, right?

I guess my question is that the price you pay for simpler reasoning is performance overhead of having to pass the collection to your actors, in scala?

I was thinking of doing some benchmark tests to this effect (selection sort, quick sort etc;) but because one is functional and one is imperative - I will not be comparing apples with apples from an algorithm viewpoint.

I would really appreciate any views you guys have on the above to give me some ideas to get me started.
Many thanks.

Comment: Parallel collections, added in 2.9, use a divide-and-conquer algorithm as you described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nice thing about Scala is that you can do concurrency the Java way if you want.  All the Java classes are available.

So it really boils down to the difference between a model where you have threads with concurrent access to mutable variables, and a model where you have stateful actors which send messages to each other but do not peek into each others' internals.  And you're absolutely right that in some scenarios you have to trade off performance against ease of getting the code correct.

I generally find as a rough rule of thumb that if you're going to have a pile of threads spending a significant amount of time waiting for a lock to open up, using a Java model, and there is no clean way to separate the work to avoid having everyone waiting for that resource, and if the execution switches between threads quickly, then the Java model is far superior to an actor model where the actor sends an "I'm done" message back to a supervisor, which then sends out a "Here's new work!" message to an existing non-busy actor.  Sorting algorithms, depending on how you envision them, can very much fall into this category.

For most everything else, the performance penalty associated with actors doesn't amount to much as far as I've seen.  If you can conceive of your problem as lots and lots of reactive elements (i.e. they only need time when they've received a message), then actors can scale particularly well (millions *available*, though only a handful are working at any given instant); with threads, you'd need to have some sort of extra internal state to keep track of who should be doing what work, since you couldn't handle that many active threads.

Comment: Thank you Rex, that gives me some more clarity around the whole subject area.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to point out here that Scala does not copy arguments passed to actors, so actors can share whatever it is passed to them.

As opposed to Erlang, it is the programmer's responsibility to avoid sharing mutable stuff. However, there is no penalty in sharing immutable stuff, since there's no need to lock it, as all accesses to it are read-only. And Scala has strong support for immutable data structures.